# Three.js ColladaLoader failed to load model: some elements seem to have no vertices

Tags: three.js, collada

I tried to import models from the 3D Warehouse, but some models fail to load (error in ColladaLoader.js (line 2808)
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'input' of null). I experienced this error with a lot of different models from 3D warehouse.

I prepared a fiddle (elcsiga/rep1z1xt/4), it loads the model from a different domain via ajax (CORS violation), however it worked me in Chrome.

A fully working example (fails to load model):
http://projecthost.hu/webview/jsfiddle/metro.html

Exactly same code with the monster model from three.js repository (it works):
http://projecthost.hu/webview/jsfiddle/monster.html

The collada model is available here: projecthost.hu/webview/jsfiddle/metro.dae
First I tried to download it as a .kmz file, unzip and use the .dae file in it directly. Additionally, I tried to download the .skp file, opened it in Sketchup and exported it into .dae format, but got the same error in ColladaLoader.js.

Do these models contain an unsupported geometry, or is it a bug in Collada loader?

Thanks.

Comment: You appear to have identified the problem: `vertices = null`. If you are are able to determine via the debugger if it is a model issue or a loader issue, that would be very helpful. Debug with the non-minified version of three.js.

Answer (score 0):

The Model don't have any vertices so the Loader cant create a geometry. (maybe I'm wrong)

You created the Model via Google SketchUp right?
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Using-SketchUp-Models

Answer (score 0):

find

```
var vertexData = sources[ this.vertices.input['POSITION'].source ].data;
```

in ColladaLoader.js, replace it with

```
var vertexData = [];
if (this.vertices && this.vertices.input['POSITION'].source) {
    vertexData = sources[ this.vertices.input['POSITION'].source ].data;
}
```

this can fix my problem by avoiding empty vertices. It may lost some info of dae file, but it won't harm ColladaLoader.js's function.